# I can't add child elements as treetable dynamic

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to add elements to treetable dynamically.but I can't combine arrays when merging.

```
const nodes=([]);
const children=([])
```

then I add an element to the nodes array

```
 nodes.push({
        key: keyIndex.value,
        data:{
          "name":newExplanation.value,
          "size":"100kb",
          "type":"Folder"

        },
      })
```

This is how I push on my second string

```
children.push({
            children:[
              {
                key: tempRoot.value + '-0' ,
                data: {
                  "name": Explanation.value,
                  "size": "100kb",
                  "type": "Folder"

                }
              }]

          })
```

then I want to add a child node element under this element and I want to combine these two arrays. But they don't get together, they seem like two separate elements in an array.
for example nodes[0:{first element},
{second element]

Here's how I do the merge

```
let r = nodes.concat({...children})
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you push in children in the same way as in nodes like this

```
children.push({
    key: tempRoot.value + '-0' ,
    data: {
        "name": Explanation.value,
        "size": "100kb",
        "type": "Folder"
    }
});
```

and then concatenate like this

```
let r = nodes.concat(children);
```

Comment: but I want to get the array too. Is there a way to do that? For example { key:0,data{foo:bla,thing:bla},children[key:0,bla:bla] like that